# Wordpress Plugin: Demon Image Annotation

Tags: plugins, errors

I've been having issues with [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/demon-image-annotation/).
What it does is that as long as an image in your blog post has an "id", then every commenter can hover over the image and leave a note directly in the image/photo.
It is syncronized with the WP comment system and so the image/phot note will appear as comment with a small thumbnail of the picture one has commented on.

This seems to be the only up to date plugin of its kind. I really need this function for my blog, but I would never be able to write a plugin like that myself, so I need to get this to work somehow.
The original idea for the plugin came from [here](http://www.dannychoo.com/post/en/26104/A+Week+in+Tokyo+65.html).

Here's an [example post](http://www.zoomingjapan.com/2011/image-test-hover/) where you can hover over the images and leave notes on them.
It works perfectly fine, however when I try to leave a comment to the post (without leaving an image note, so we're talking about a normal comment) while I'm not logged in, I get the following error message:

> noted on #img-46
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /hermes/bosweb25a/b155/ipg.zoomingjapancom/wp-content/plugins/demon-image-annotation/imageannotation.php:178)
>   in /hermes/bosweb25a/b155/ipg.zoomingjapancom/wp-comments-post.php on
>   line 95
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /hermes/bosweb25a/b155/ipg.zoomingjapancom/wp-content/plugins/demon-image-annotation/imageannotation.php:178)
>   in /hermes/bosweb25a/b155/ipg.zoomingjapancom/wp-comments-post.php on
>   line 96
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /her.../wp-content/plugins/demon-image-annotation/imageannotation.php:178)
>   in /her.../wp-comments-post.php on
>   line 97
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /her.../wp-content/plugins/demon-image-annotation/imageannotation.php:178)
>   in
>   /her.../wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 934

Here's the plugins php code that is causing the problem: [@Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3yU5k9NZ)
It might have something to do with the "echo" command in line 178. I tried "return" instead, but then the thumbnail of the image you commented on is not shown in the comment anymore. There must be another way.

I've already tried a few things and it seems that other people don't have the same problem with the plugin, so I was wondering if it's actually the plugin or something else that's causing this problem.

This is quite tough, but I hope somebody here can help me figure it out.

EDIT:
As for now I'm trying to call the javascript in a better way!

So what looks like this in the plugin's php file:

```
echo "<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>\n";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='". $plugindir ."/js/jquery.annotate.js'></script>\n";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='". $plugindir ."/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.js'></script>\n";
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='". $plugindir ."/js/jquery.md5.js'></script>\n";
```

Should look somehow like this: (this is a shortened version)

```
function add_my_javascripts() {
    /* If this is the admin area of WordPress, don't do anything */
    if( is_admin() )
        return;

    /* Register all of our scripts */

    wp_register_script('jquery-ui-perso', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.2.packed.js', array('jquery', 'tab-renamer'));
    wp_register_script('md5', 'http://zoomingjapan.com/wp-content/plugins/demon-image-annotation/js/jquery.md5.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-perso'));
    wp_register_script('jquery.annotate', 'http://zoomingjapan.com/wp-content/plugins/demon-image-annotation/js/jquery.annotate.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-perso', 'md5'));

    /* Enqueue the ones that need to be enqueued */

   wp_enqueue_script('jquery.annotate');


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_javascripts');
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, so I think I'm calling it wrong. Maybe I got the dependencies wrong?
I don't een know what that md5.js is supposed to do, so I'm not sure.
Anybody knows?

**EDIT:** I've marked the only answer as accepted answer, however there's still no solution to this and I'm not the only one struggling with this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin is trying to echo data (re-sending the headers) after they have been sent.

Here is line 178 of the plugin `echo "<div id=\"comment-".$str."\"><a href='#".$str."'>noted on #".$imgIDNow."</a></div>";`

I would need more information on which page the plugin was failing on. What the plugin does, what you are trying to do to be able to help you further.

Comment: I think the issue is the opposite, something else is trying to send headers, but this plugin has already sent content to the browser. A cursory glance at the code shows JavaScript is handled incorrectly, I'd question the overall quality of this plugin.

Comment: @BandonRandon: Thank you very much for your answer. That's exactly what I wrote in my post, that's why I tried to exchange the "echo" with "return", but it didn't work. I've updated my question with a lot more information now, so if you have time please have a look at it :) Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Milo: Well, I need this function for my blog and because there's no way that I can write a plugin like that myself, I need to get this to work somehow :/ ... You think I have to modify s.th. else instead of the plugin then?

Comment: @Milo That's what I ment I just read the error backwards :)

Comment: @japanworm what happens if you comment out lines 168-195 the problem is that it is trying to treat all comments like annotations and you need a way to tell them apart I just haven't figured it out yet. Also it seems the aurthor put out an update 9 days ago is that the version you're using?

Comment: @BandonRandon: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me! I really appreaciate it! :) Yes, I'm using the latest version of the plugin. I also was hoping to get rid of these issues by the update, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: @BandonRandon: Were you able to figure something out? :) I actually updated my question, so if you have a minute, please have a look at it, thank you :)

Comment: @Milo: I'm trying to call the javascript correctly as a first step. See my updated question for more information :)

Comment: @japanworm  I just installed the plugin on my test site (http://dev.brandondukes.com/wordpress/2011/10/16/137/) and it's working fine with WordPress 3.3 this means you probably have another plugin conflict.

Comment: @BandonRandon: I think it's a really buggy plugin to begin with. The newest version 2.4.7 doesn't work at all. The version 2.4.6 is only partly working and 2.4.5 causes the prolbem I mentioned. I already deactivated all plugins. I still get the same issue. It's a problem with the Wordpress comment system and the plugin interfering with it. When I dactivate the option that the plugin syncronizes with the WP comment system, I don't get the error, but the image notes also stop working ... *sigh*

Comment: Wierd, I'm having no issue wit 2.4.7 with WP 3.3. Wonder if it's a theme issue.